# overriding class with !important tag

Tags: jquery, css, overriding

I am trying to override an !important tag for a hover class in a plugin I am using.

The css for the element/class in the plugin is as follows:

```
input.fl-submit {
    background: #555;
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.12, rgb(60,60,60)),
        color-stop(1, rgb(85,85,85))
    );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        center bottom,
        rgb(60,60,60) 12%,
        rgb(85,85,85) 100%
    );
}

input.fl-submit:hover {
    background: #282828 !important;
}
```

I am trying to change the background property, which I can do with an !important tag for input.fl-submit, but because the hover property already has an !important tag I can't work out how to override this.  I have tried a couple of jquery methods that I found on stackoverflow already, but haven't been able to get it working, so would be grateful for any help.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: This is a good illustration of why `!important` should never be used.  If you can edit the CSS, rework it using [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) rather than `!important`.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use Javascript:

```
        document.styleSheets[1].deleteRule(0);
    var background = '#000000';
    document.styleSheets[1].insertRule('input.fl-submit:hover { background: ' + background + '; }', 0);
    //Another Way of doing...
    document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.background = background;
```

[More Info](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/cssrule.shtml)

Comment: Thanks.  I am not sure how to amend this script for my particular purposes.  I can see where to adjust the background, but not sure how to refer to the CSS file which is called "formloom-page1-css"

Comment: You could do same with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/NqNh3/ Well idk.. exactly the same....  Wait did it have to be hover value?

Comment: You need to know the index of the css in the DOM so you can tell to the 'styleSheets' array the index of the 'formloom-page1-css' css sheet the index is zero based so in my example i am reffering to the second css sheet and deleting/adding the first rule wich is the background.

Answer (score 1):

The entire idea of the `!important` tag is so that you COULDN'T override it. I am assuming you don't have access to the CSS and can't just remove it, therefore, the only solution I have is to give it another background style with another `!important` modifier (this will override the previous one).

Comment: ... another `!important` modifier _and_ a more specific selector.

Comment: I am assuming he can't modify the `CSS`

Comment: Yes, I can't modify the CSS or the html easily.  It is generated by the plugin.

Comment: I am sure which color would "win" - the style that came last.

Comment: Assuming you know which stylesheet came last.